# Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\bab2\index.php</b> on line <b>126</b>

Tags: php

Warning: A non-numeric value encountered in C:\xampp\htdocs\epard\cart.php on line 126

```html
if (($nmbr+$key)>52){
                    if (dec_to_char($nmbr)!=null){
                        echo dec_to_char(($nmbr+$key)-52);
                    } else {
                        echo $nmbr;
                    }
```

Thank you

Comment: What values are in those variables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is not clear. But if you just want to avoid warning, use this:
`if(is_numeric($nmbr)&&is_numeric($key)){ //youre code }`